# new Map() State get specific key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state checkedItems: new Map();

and when I'm trying to console.log(checkedItem) i get this:

> Map(3) {"1" => true, "1.5" => true, "2" => false}

How can I get only the true one in an array.

Comment: `checkedItems.get("1")` or what?

Comment: no here you give me only the value of one I want an array like [1,1.5] without 2 because 2 is false

Comment: Ah, got it - all the `true` values.

Comment: yes, how can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maps have the [`entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries) method which returns [an iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) over the key-value pairs. Iterators are lazy, so you have to consume it to transform it. One way is to turn into an array and then use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the keys:

```
Array.from(checkedItems.entries())
    .filter(([key, value]) => value)
    .map(([key]) => key)
```

However, there is a better way to do this lazily using [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator):

```js
function* filter(predicate, it) {
  for (const item of it) {
    if (predicate(item))
      yield item;
  }
}

function* map(fn, it) {
  for (const item of it) {
    yield fn(item);
  }
}


const checkedItems = new Map()
  .set("1"  , true)
  .set("1.5", true)
  .set("2"  , false);
  
const iterator = checkedItems.entries();
const onlyTrue = filter(([key, value]) => value, iterator);
const onlyTrueKeys = map(([key]) => key, onlyTrue);

console.log(Array.from(onlyTrueKeys));
```

This will only generate a single array at the end.

The `filter` and `map` generator functions can be combined together

```
const onlyTrueKeys = map(
  ([key]) => key,
  filter(
    ([key, value]) => value,
    checkedItems.entries()
  )
);
```

But it might be easier to partially apply and then compose them with a helper function:

```js
function* filter(predicate, it) {
  for (const item of it) {
    if (predicate(item))
      yield item;
  }
}

function* map(fn, it) {
  for (const item of it) {
    yield fn(item);
  }
}

function transform(iterator, ...transformers) {
  return transformers.reduce((it, transform) => transform(it), iterator);
}


const checkedItems = new Map()
  .set("1"  , true)
  .set("1.5", true)
  .set("2"  , false);

const onlyTrueKeys = transform(
  checkedItems.entries(),
  
  filter.bind(null, ([key, value]) => value),
  map.bind(null, ([key]) => key),
  Array.from
);

console.log(onlyTrueKeys);
```

This can also be made into a class, if you prefer:

```js
function* filter(it, pred) {
  for (const item of it) {
    if (pred(item))
      yield item;
  }
}

function* map(it, fn) {
  for (const item of it) {
    yield fn(item);
  }
}

class LazyTransformer {
  constructor(iterator) {
    this.iterator = iterator;
  }
  
  filter(predicate) {
    this.iterator = filter(this.iterator, predicate);
    return this;
  }
  
  map(fn) {
    this.iterator = map(this.iterator, fn);
    return this;
  }
  
  toArray() {
    return Array.from(this.iterator);
  }
}


const checkedItems = new Map()
  .set("1"  , true)
  .set("1.5", true)
  .set("2"  , false);

const transformer = new LazyTransformer(checkedItems.entries());

transformer
  .filter(([key, value]) => value)
  .map(([key]) => key);

console.log(transformer.toArray());
```